# This code is supposed to convert data from my spread sheet to a document and then to a pdf, but its only doing the last row

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script which is supposed to export data from a google sheet, enter it into a document and store that in the proper folder, then take that new document and turn it into a PDF, and then store it into it's own folder.

When I run both functions independently, they executer right and go until all documents have been created.

With them put together as shown below, they only do it to the last row of data and not the other 13...

Any ideas why it isn't looping?

```js
function createDoc() {
  console.log("first");

  // To pull the headers of each column - insert spreadsheet URL and header array
  var headers = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('1846CxmPdoc2VBW6GxaybCPW1_u2swO1jooIBiF2Yl90', 'A2:AA2');
  // To pull the variables for each header - insert spreadsheet URL and variable array
  var variables = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('1846CxmPdoc2VBW6GxaybCPW1_u2swO1jooIBiF2Yl90', 'A3:AA14');
  // To pull the template document for the header and variables to be input by the program
  var templateId = '1ONhT3n4Pr49BL6xEM_ykO9UVi8xZriA2fVAZjoFi2qI';


  //Loop to run through all variables in spreadsheet
  for(var i = 0; i < variables.values.length; i++) {
    
    //Create the variables which will be used to transfer the data from the spreadsheet to the document. The first cell in the row is 0 and then from left to right, increases in its number. Only change variable name and the number.
    var client = variables.values[i][0];
    var agent = variables.values[i][1];
    var aaddress = variables.values[i][2];
    var acity = variables.values[i][3];
    var caddress = variables.values[i][4];
    var ccity = variables.values[i][5];
    var suopen = variables.values[i][6];
    var suclose = variables.values[i][7];
    var moopen = variables.values[i][8];
    var moclose = variables.values[i][9];
    var tuopen = variables.values[i][10];
    var tuclose = variables.values[i][11];
    var weopen = variables.values[i][12];
    var weclose = variables.values[i][13];
    var thopen = variables.values[i][14];
    var thclose = variables.values[i][15];
    var fropen = variables.values[i][16];
    var frclose = variables.values[i][17];
    var saopen = variables.values[i][18];
    var saclose = variables.values[i][19];
    var price = variables.values[i][20];
    var appayment = variables.values[i][21];
    var mpayment = variables.values[i][22];
    var junepayment = variables.values[i][23];
    var julypayment = variables.values[i][24];
    var aupayment = variables.values[i][25];
    var sepayment = variables.values[i][26];
  }

  // Make a copy of the template file
  const documentId = DriveApp.getFileById('1ONhT3n4Pr49BL6xEM_ykO9UVi8xZriA2fVAZjoFi2qI').makeCopy().getId();

  // Rename the copied file
  DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName('2022' + " " + client + " " + 'Pool Management Proposal');
    
  // Set copied file's destination variable;
  var folderId = DriveApp.getFolderById('1YVhLzwZ9CI5-iTR1SKHF5ykNVqZQvQY9');
  
  // Send copied file to this folder
  var fileId = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId);
  fileId.moveTo(folderId); 

  // Get the document body as a variable
  const  OpenDoc = DocumentApp.openById(documentId);
  const body = OpenDoc.getBody();

  // Insert Data from sheet to document. ##info## is the placeholder text in the document, and the second variable is the variable we set above to codify the column's data in the sheet.
  body.replaceText('##Agent Name##', agent);
  body.replaceText('##Agent Address##', aaddress);
  body.replaceText('##Agent City/Zip##', acity);
  body.replaceText('##Client Name##', client)
  body.replaceText('##Client Address##', caddress);
  body.replaceText('##Client City/Zip##', ccity);
  body.replaceText('##Contract Price##', price);
  body.replaceText('##April Payment##', appayment);
  body.replaceText('##May Payment##', mpayment);
  body.replaceText('##June Payment##', junepayment);
  body.replaceText('##July Payment##', julypayment);
  body.replaceText('##August Payment##', aupayment);
  body.replaceText('##September Payment##', sepayment);
  body.replaceText('##Sunday Open##', suopen);
  body.replaceText('##Sunday Close##', suclose);
  body.replaceText('##Monday Open##', moopen);
  body.replaceText('##Monday Close##', moclose);
  body.replaceText('##Tuesday Open##', tuopen);
  body.replaceText('##Tuesday Close##', tuclose);
  body.replaceText('##Wednesday Open##', weopen);
  body.replaceText('##Wednesday Close##', weclose);
  body.replaceText('##Thursday Open##', thopen);
  body.replaceText('##Thursday Close##', thclose);
  body.replaceText('##Friday Open##', fropen);
  body.replaceText('##Friday Close##', frclose);
  body.replaceText('##Saturday Open##', saopen);
  body.replaceText('##Saturday Close##', saclose);

  OpenDoc.saveAndClose();

  var pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1_idXGdZo0l_U1IxuaLDUqrk0HjdfZvsg"); 
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId);
  var theBlob = templateFile.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
  var newPDFFile = folderId.createFile(theBlob);
  newPDFFile.moveTo(pdfFolder);

  var fileName = templateFile.getName().replace(".", ""); 
  // otherwise filename will be shortened after full stop   
  newPDFFile.setName(fileName + ".pdf").getId();
}
```

Comment: I don't use Sheets very often but I noticed that you did not specify a sheet/tab.  It works just fine if you specify the sheet with the range as 'Sheet1:A2:AA2'

Comment: My guess is that you would have seen an error if you had check executions.

Comment: @Cooper would you mind giving me an example so I can try incorporating it?

Comment: What do you receive if you do `console.log(variables.values.length)`? Is there any chance you might have exceeded the maximum script time?

Comment: @ale13 No it doesn't exceed anything. I am not entirely sure what the '''.length''' does yet, but the '''variables.values''' sets the requirement for '''i''' to continue on with the loop until there are no values left.

Comment: Google sheets gets values in a matrix from, i.e. an array of arrays. The first array is an array of rows containing arrays of the cells in each row from left to right. What you're saying with the loop is "Do these operations once for each row of the range I give you". Then it also becomes clear why the the other operations had to go into the body of the loop, not after.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunk() {
  const vs = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get("ssid",'Sheet0!A1:J21');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(1,1,vs.values.length,vs.values[0].length).setValues(vs.values);
}
```

I thought about what you were saying and you're right it doesn't seem to act like and array so I tried this:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  let vs = Array.from(Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get("ssid",'Sheet0!A1:J21').values);
  let va = vs.filter((r,i) => i % 2 == 0);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(1,1,va.length,va[0].length).setValues(va);
}
```

My Sheet0:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 14 | 5 | 10 | 17 | 1 | 15 | 10 | 2 | 6 |
| 12 | 10 | 2 | 19 | 2 | 1 | 19 | 6 | 10 | 7 |
| 4 | 7 | 17 | 11 | 17 | 3 | 8 | 7 | 2 | 5 |
| 10 | 17 | 14 | 13 | 2 | 6 | 18 | 6 | 1 | 11 |
| 15 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 19 | 9 | 1 | 4 | 14 |
| 1 | 6 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 10 | 5 | 5 | 17 | 12 |
| 15 | 1 | 8 | 4 | 5 | 7 | 13 | 19 | 0 | 7 |
| 14 | 18 | 9 | 10 | 13 | 3 | 9 | 9 | 19 | 14 |
| 11 | 1 | 5 | 17 | 17 | 15 | 2 | 6 | 8 | 16 |
| 0 | 14 | 6 | 4 | 18 | 12 | 8 | 8 | 17 | 4 |
| 10 | 15 | 13 | 7 | 3 | 17 | 13 | 17 | 9 | 3 |
| 3 | 16 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 7 | 6 | 3 | 17 | 3 |
| 17 | 18 | 12 | 13 | 13 | 10 | 9 | 14 | 16 | 11 |
| 8 | 6 | 2 | 10 | 14 | 7 | 6 | 0 | 17 | 12 |
| 13 | 12 | 19 | 9 | 12 | 11 | 19 | 14 | 0 | 18 |
| 18 | 17 | 0 | 0 | 18 | 9 | 19 | 14 | 2 | 1 |
| 7 | 9 | 17 | 12 | 19 | 0 | 3 | 17 | 17 | 16 |
| 15 | 11 | 0 | 6 | 4 | 18 | 8 | 16 | 8 | 15 |
| 10 | 4 | 5 | 10 | 13 | 8 | 7 | 3 | 13 | 9 |
| 10 | 2 | 9 | 11 | 10 | 0 | 17 | 2 | 19 | 7 |

My Sheet1:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 10 | 2 | 19 | 2 | 1 | 19 | 6 | 10 | 7 |
| 10 | 17 | 14 | 13 | 2 | 6 | 18 | 6 | 1 | 11 |
| 1 | 6 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 10 | 5 | 5 | 17 | 12 |
| 14 | 18 | 9 | 10 | 13 | 3 | 9 | 9 | 19 | 14 |
| 0 | 14 | 6 | 4 | 18 | 12 | 8 | 8 | 17 | 4 |
| 3 | 16 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 7 | 6 | 3 | 17 | 3 |
| 8 | 6 | 2 | 10 | 14 | 7 | 6 | 0 | 17 | 12 |
| 18 | 17 | 0 | 0 | 18 | 9 | 19 | 14 | 2 | 1 |
| 15 | 11 | 0 | 6 | 4 | 18 | 8 | 16 | 8 | 15 |
| 10 | 2 | 9 | 11 | 10 | 0 | 17 | 2 | 19 | 7 |

Clearly this is now behaving as an array.

Then I realized that it must be returning JSON because this also worked.

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  let vs = JSON.parse(Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get("ssid",'Sheet0!A1:J21')).values;
  let va = vs.filter((r,i) => i % 2 == 0);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(1,1,va.length,va[0].length).setValues(va);
}
```

Comment: Okay I see what you are saying. The only issue is that there is only one sheet on the google sheet. It is pulling the info fine, it just isn't continuing with the loop when I add both functions.

Comment: So like I said I don't use that technique very much and it took me awhile to realize what you were saying because my first example didn't test iterability of the object but I was surprized that it behaved as a 2d array...not sure why.

Comment: I used to work with a chief electronics tech in the navy on and off and I remember that he would often say I'm not sure that I understand what I know about this. And I think that applies here as well.

Answer (score 0):

You know... I have only been coding for like.. 5 days.

I solved my problem however, and its odd that out of all the responses, no one simply said to "turn them all into one function", lol.

All i had to do was turn it into one function, and it pulls the data for one row, creates the document, saves the document into whatever folder I tell it to, then creates the PDF, then stores it into a folder I tell it to. Next I will make it auto email that PDF with a template document as the body. If anyone wants the code, here it is...

```js
function createDoc() {
  console.log("pulling data and template");
  var headers = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('1846CxmPdoc2VBW6GxaybCPW1_u2swO1jooIBiF2Yl90', 'log!A2:AA2');
  var variables = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('1846CxmPdoc2VBW6GxaybCPW1_u2swO1jooIBiF2Yl90', 'log!A3:AA14');
  var templateId = '1ONhT3n4Pr49BL6xEM_ykO9UVi8xZriA2fVAZjoFi2qI';

  console.log("creating loop");
  for (var i = 0; i < variables.values.length; i++) {
    var client = variables.values[i][0];
    var agent = variables.values[i][1];
    var aaddress = variables.values[i][2];
    var acity = variables.values[i][3];
    var caddress = variables.values[i][4];
    var ccity = variables.values[i][5];
    var suopen = variables.values[i][6];
    var suclose = variables.values[i][7];
    var moopen = variables.values[i][8];
    var moclose = variables.values[i][9];
    var tuopen = variables.values[i][10];
    var tuclose = variables.values[i][11];
    var weopen = variables.values[i][12];
    var weclose = variables.values[i][13];
    var thopen = variables.values[i][14];
    var thclose = variables.values[i][15];
    var fropen = variables.values[i][16];
    var frclose = variables.values[i][17];
    var saopen = variables.values[i][18];
    var saclose = variables.values[i][19];
    var price = variables.values[i][20];
    var appayment = variables.values[i][21];
    var mpayment = variables.values[i][22];
    var junepayment = variables.values[i][23];
    var julypayment = variables.values[i][24];
    var aupayment = variables.values[i][25];
    var sepayment = variables.values[i][26];

    console.log("setting document Id");
    var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById('1ONhT3n4Pr49BL6xEM_ykO9UVi8xZriA2fVAZjoFi2qI').makeCopy().getId();

    console.log("setting destinations")
    var documentDestination = DriveApp.getFolderById('1YVhLzwZ9CI5-iTR1SKHF5ykNVqZQvQY9');
    var pdfDestination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1_idXGdZo0l_U1IxuaLDUqrk0HjdfZvsg");
  
    console.log("creating document");
    DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName('2022' + " " + client + " " + 'Pool Management Proposal');
    var document = DocumentApp.openById(documentId); 
    var body = document.getBody();
    body.replaceText('##Agent Name##', agent);
    body.replaceText('##Agent Address##', aaddress);
    body.replaceText('##Agent City/Zip##', acity);
    body.replaceText('##Client Name##', client)
    body.replaceText('##Client Address##', caddress);
    body.replaceText('##Client City/Zip##', ccity);
    body.replaceText('##Contract Price##', price);
    body.replaceText('##April Payment##', appayment);
    body.replaceText('##May Payment##', mpayment);
    body.replaceText('##June Payment##', junepayment);
    body.replaceText('##July Payment##', julypayment);
    body.replaceText('##August Payment##', aupayment);
    body.replaceText('##September Payment##', sepayment);
    body.replaceText('##Sunday Open##', suopen);
    body.replaceText('##Sunday Close##', suclose);
    body.replaceText('##Monday Open##', moopen);
    body.replaceText('##Monday Close##', moclose);
    body.replaceText('##Tuesday Open##', tuopen);
    body.replaceText('##Tuesday Close##', tuclose);
    body.replaceText('##Wednesday Open##', weopen);
    body.replaceText('##Wednesday Close##', weclose);
    body.replaceText('##Thursday Open##', thopen);
    body.replaceText('##Thursday Close##', thclose);
    body.replaceText('##Friday Open##', fropen);
    body.replaceText('##Friday Close##', frclose);
    body.replaceText('##Saturday Open##', saopen);
    body.replaceText('##Saturday Close##', saclose);

    console.log("moving document");
    var docFile = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId);
    docFile.moveTo(documentDestination);
  
    console.log("document creation complete");
    document.saveAndClose();
  
    console.log("converting document to PDF");
    var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId);
    var folder = 
    DriveApp.getFolderById('1_idXGdZo0l_U1IxuaLDUqrk0HjdfZvsg');
    var theBlob = templateFile.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
    var newPDFFile = folder.createFile(theBlob); 
 
    console.log("naming PDF");
    var fileName = templateFile.getName().replace(".", ""); //otherwise filename will be shortened after full stop   
    newPDFFile.setName(fileName + ".pdf");

    console.log("PDF creation complete");
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly have you changed here? Rather than "turn[ing] it into one function" it looks like you put the doc creation into the loop?

Comment: That is all I did, that is all I needed to do.